# Display first 100 chars of field in apex:pageBlockTable

Tags: visualforce

I have a list of account bound to a apex:pageblocktable. 
I need a way of displaying just the first 100 chars of the field description on the table.

```
<apex:column headerValue="{!$ObjectType.Account.Fields.Description.Label}">
       <apex:outputField value="{!s.Description}"   />
</apex:column>
```

Tried changing it to

```
<apex:column headerValue="{!$ObjectType.Account.Fields.Description.Label}">
                    <apex:outputText value="{!if(String.IsBlank(s.Description),'',s.Description.left(100))}"   />
                </apex:column>
```

But throws

> Error: Unknown function String.IsBlank. Check spelling

Any other way we can achieve this?

Comment: `LEFT`? https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&language=en_US#LEFT

Comment: If you're looking to take up "all available space, but no more", consider using `slds-truncate` if you're using slds, or `text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden` otherwise. This looks nicer from a UX perspective.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

there is a simple way to do this

```
<apex:outputText value="{!left(Account.description,100)}"   />
```

Comment: Thanks Doug, if description returns a null, wouldnt it throw exception?

Comment: No, it will not throw an exception. The VF functions are more tolerant than the Apex string functions. You can check it out for yourself, it will work fine with null.

Comment: Awesome... works like charm

Answer (score 2):

I added below to truncate string.

```
<apex:outputText value="{!IF(LEN(Account.description) > 100, LEFT(Account.description, 97) + '...', Account.description)}"  />
```